# Ruby One Line Or Conditional with Nil Checks

Tags: ruby, null, conditional-statements

In Ruby, I would like to do a single line conditional with an or statement that has multiple checks for nil. For example:

```
warn = my_val >= max if max or my_val <= min if min
```

It's possible that max and/or min will be nil, so I only want to do the comparison if the one or both of the values exist. Is there a way to do this type of logic in one line?

Comment: warn = (max and my_val >= max) or (min and my_val <= min)

Comment: if max and min are nil, what value do you want for ` warn` ?

Comment: If both are nil, then i would want false for warn.

Comment: Suppose you came across a question to thought was interesting and had an idea for an answer. While preparing your answer you noticed the green check mark flash on, **a mere 20 minutes after the question was posted**. Would you be annoyed, maybe just a bit?

Comment: @CarySwoveland moreover, the accepted answer wasn't quite correct - but a correct answer was provided above in comments (and happens to be the same as yours :) )

Comment: @PennyM, thanks for pointing that out. I missed that.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra, I just posted an answer that I see (after being informed by PennyM) that is the same as your comment). Please post an answer and I'll retract mine.

Comment: My point was that you should wait awhile before selecting an answer. I suggest at least a couple of hours. There is no rush.  A quick-draw answer may discourage other, possibly better, answers, and as I suggested in my earlier comment, is inconsiderate to those still preparing their answer.I suggest you remove the greenie from my answer and see what other ideas readers come up with.

Comment: @PinnyM, "how do I feel? :-)" , you asked (before deleting). I feel like a mere scribe. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland - valid point. I didn't consider that when selecting an answer. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
warn = (max and my_val >= max) or (min and my_val <= min)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume the following:

```
> max = 3;  min = 0; my_val = 0;
```

@PardeepDhingra's answer seems correct.

```
> warn = (max && my_val >= max) || (min && my_val <= min)
=> true
```

The accepted answer by @ThomasHaratyk appears to have a logical flaw with this scenario:

```
> warn = max ? my_val >= max :  ( min ? my_val <= min : false )
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution :

```
warn = !my_val.between? (min || -Float::INFINITY), (max || Float::INFINITY)
```

*Old wrong solution for comments context*

```
# warn = max ? my_val >= max :  ( min ? my_val <= min : false )
```

Comment: @fowlball1010 if my_val < min, but there is a max, won't this return an incorrect result?

Comment: I ran this in irb with my_val = 5, min = 6, and max = 3, it returned true, which was expected. Is there a specific scenario where you triggered false with such constraints?

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk Indeed the flaw is demonstrable, given `max = 3; min = 0; my_val = 0`

Comment: Ah, that is correct, I do receive false with that when I expect true.

Comment: Almost, except the edgecases of `max` and `min` themselves are wrong.  And please don't feel the need to apologize - we're all learning here.

Comment: @PinnyM Could you explain why the edgecases are wrong ? thanks

Comment: `between?` will return true if the value matches the upper or lower bound or anything in between.  The OP wants the upper and lower bounds to be handled as outside what would normally be called 'between'.

Comment: Oh thought between was inclusive. My bad, I'm a SQL guy that's why :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
warn = my_val >= max or my_val <= min unless max.nil? and min.nil?
```

Comment: My apologies, I updated the question to reflect that I'm okay with doing the comparison if only one of the values of max or min are supplied.

Comment: @fowlball1010 just changed the `unless .. or` to `unless .. and`

Comment: When I use that with a min value set and a max value of nil, it throws an error for comparison of Fixnum with nil.

Comment: @fowlball1010 Yup. That's what I get for not testing code. it worked when it was `or` but setting to `and` breaks things unsurprisingly. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seriously think that anyone would pull in `ActiveSupport` just for [its `try`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try) for such a simple task, but I can't just not suggest it. It kind of reminds me of the old "jQuery way of solving everything" and looks almost readable.

```ruby
warn = max.try(:>=, my_val) || min.try(:<=, my_val)
```

Just in case it's not clear enough: don't pull in ActiveSupport just for that unless you are already using it (in Rails or for whatever other reason). But if you like the readability, you can add ActiveSupport and require only `active_support/core_ext/object/try` for a minimal memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't use my original answer, let me try a real-life one:

```
def doit(min, max, my_value)
  case [min.nil?, max.nil?]
  when [false, false] then my_value <= min || my_value >= max
  when [false, true ] then my_value <= min
  when [true,  false] then my_value >= max
  when [true,  true ] then false
  end
end

doit 5,7,8     #=> true 
doit 5,7,4     #=> true 
doit 5,7,6     #=> false 
doit nil,7,8   #=> true 
doit 5,nil,4   #=> true 
doit 5,nil,8   #=> false 
doit nil,nil,4 #=> false
```